# How to configure rails_admin to change integer input field into select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, configuration, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I am using `rails_admin` with `devise`. I have a plain `User` model (having the typical `devise` attributes) as well as an additional `integer` type attribute called `role_type`. When I view `http://0.0.0.0:5000/admin/user/1/edit` in the browser, I see ten `devise` attributes, plus my `Role type` (though it is an `type="number"` `input` field) whereas I want it to be a `select` drop down menu. I have done some searching around, and have added a configuration to `rails_admin.rb` as well as a corresponding partial, and though I get the drop down I want, *it's the only thing I get for the whole user edit view*.

I want to configure the way `rails_admin` displays the `:role_type` field, while (obviously) also being able to edit the rest of the `User` fields.

**db/migrate/20131119000715_add_role_type_to_user.rb**

```
class AddRoleTypeToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role_type, :integer, null: false, default: 0
  end
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ROLES = ['default', 'admin', 'moderator']
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails_admin', github: 'sferik/rails_admin'
```

**config/initializers/rails_admin.rb**

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model User do
    edit do
      field :role_type do
        partial 'form'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/views/rails_admin/main/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form.select :role_type, User::ROLES.each_with_index.map { |e, i| [e, i] } %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `role_type_enum` method in your model that returns `User::ROLES`.

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Enumeration

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late but I came accross this problem today, and found a solution!
If anyone stumbles on this: by changing `field: you_column_name do` to `configure: your_column_name do` in your rails_admin initializer, it should still show all your other fields and change only the one specified.

Thanks to the doc: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields